# Java .replace not working

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm trying to edit a JPQL query and .replace just isn't working in this one instance.

Can anyone help me as to why?

```
qcJpql = qcJpql.replace("deal.entity.dealproduct dp", "product.entity.productdistribution dp");
```

However the below bit works fine:

```
qcJpql = qcJpql.replace(" p.", " dp.");
```

qcJpql is a String.

Thanks very much for any answers!

Comment: What is the original string?

Comment: You should check your codes. I don't think the method `replace()` impl. has a bug. show us how it didn't work. Have you checked, `TAB vs. Space`?

Comment: Un-tagging regex. `String#replace` does not parse regular expressions in its given arguments.

Comment: @Mena: However, if OP needs to replace a string containing both regular and Unicode spaces, a regex could be of help... Try `qcJpql = qcJpql.replaceAll("(?U)deal\\.entity\\.dealproduct\\s+dp", "product.entity.productdistribution dp");`

Comment: @MHardwick select dp.product.productId from deal.entity.DealProduct dp where dp.dealDataConfiguration.deal.clientOrganisation.organisationId = 65380001

Comment: @Mena Actually I was thinking replace all might be an answer hence why I put it there, like what stribizhev suggested.

Comment: @stribizhev I tried that but it didn't work still, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Replace is case sensitive. Since you said in the comments your string was:

```
select dp.product.productId from deal.entity.DealProduct dp where dp.dealDataConfiguration.deal.clientOrganisation.organisationId = 65380001 –
```

It's not finding "deal.entity.DealProduct dp" because you're looking for "deal.entity.dealproduct dp". Just change the case on the search string.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you! It still doesn't work but that was a complete oversight on my part.